# Need instruction : To Install ELK stack in On-Prem setup with persistant Volumes using Helm charts

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elk

I need help with persistent volumes set while setting up ELK stack to monitor my kubernetes cluster.

I tired

```html
helm install elasticsearch elasticsearch
```

error  :
0/2 nodes are available: 2 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

but since i am runnng on prem the persistant voumles are not getting created . How do i specify persistant volumes in the helm install command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In glancing [through the chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/templates/statefulset.yaml#L26-L44), it looks like it is using Persistent Volume Claim Templates in your Statefulset.

> The volumeClaimTemplates will provide stable storage using PersistentVolumes provisioned by a PersistentVolume Provisioner.

The chart checks if [persistence.labels.enabled](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml#L122-L124) is True, and if it is it adds your labels, and then it adds your annotations, and then finally it uses your [.Values.volumeClaimTemplate](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/values.yaml#L91-L95).  So, in the end if you don't change anything in the values, it looks like it will try to create persistent volumes with these specs using your default provisioner:

```
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

So, you should check what your default provisioner is

```
kubectl get storageclasses
```

For example, mine is aws-ebs, and so in my case it would create AWS EBS Volumes.  This doc explains [how to change your Default storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/) if yours isn't set to something you want.

> Depending on the installation method, your Kubernetes cluster may be
> deployed with an existing StorageClass that is marked as default. This
> default StorageClass is then used to dynamically provision storage for
> PersistentVolumeClaims that do not require any specific storage class.
> See PersistentVolumeClaim documentation for details

You also should be able to specify the Storage Class you want to use, and then pass in something like this in a separate values file:

```
volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi
```

```
helm install --name elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch -f values.yaml -f custom-values.yaml
```